# Width of container decided by the width of the second child

Tags: html, css

I have a container `div` with structure like below:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title"> </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  <div>
```

I want the width of `.container` depend on the width of `content`.

I found some solution such as [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/qs8GJ/)

But it's not what I want.
You can see if I change the order, the width still depend on the first child:
[FIDDLE DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/qs8GJ/186/)

**EDIT**

I may add some context, the `title` in my program is very long, I am OK if it will be broken in several lines. 
But if the width depends on the widest child(`title`). there will be too much space for `content`.
I think this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9sdmns4d/) may be more helpful.

Comment: I am going to leave office, I can not access stack overflow in my home because of the great wall of Chinese net, I will check all comments and answers tomorrow, sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: In your example you have defined the width of the image, so if I understand the question correctly, why can't you define the width of `.container`?

Comment: `.container` will have the width of the most big child, no matter what you do or the order of the childs, you can make a javascript hack, but the result will be weird and dangerous

Comment: @jaunt Actually, in my code, the second div is not a image but some text code. these text code need to globalized, so the width of second div can not be fixed.

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude Yeah, I know the container will take the with of widest child, but I want the title can have several lines, because my title is a long line, if the container depends on the title, there will be so much space in container.

Comment: So your title must be `position : absolute` and container must be `position : relative`.  I will answer you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but only by utilising `display:table` and associated properties like `display:table-caption`:

```css
.title {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: top;
  background: pink;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  display: table-row;
  background: lightblue;
}
.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, quam, rerum. Repellat quasi, quis voluptatum!</div>
  <div class="content">This section determines the overall width of the structure.</div>
  <div class="footer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 .container { position : relative ;} 
 .title { position :absolute ;}
```

Comment: Clever idea. but how can we fix the position for content? I do not know the height of title.

Comment: This is more complex. As I tell you, you need Javascript at the end. With javascript you can read the height of the title and apply as margin top of the content

Answer (score -1):

```
.container{
    display: table
}
```